# Laravel email verification throttle middleware too strict

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a web application built with Laravel, it's an API and after a user creates their account, they need to verify their email, they do this by tapping a button on the front-end which sends a request to an endpoint, now, creating an account is one request, and then the immidete effect of logging in is a new request, but for some reason, after logging in and trying to tap the button to send an email verification seems to trigger an error of:

- Too Many Attempts

It only seems to appear whilst **debug** is set to `false`, and I'm trying to understand what's wrong with the throttle middleware?

What does the `6,1` mean here?

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use App\Models\User;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Email Verification Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling email verification for any
    | user that recently registered with the application. Emails may also
    | be re-sent if the user didn't receive the original email message.
    |
    */

    use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'my-url';

    /**
     * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        // sends the email, removed code for Stackoverflow as not needed
    }

    /**
     * Resend the email verification notification.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function resend(Request $request)
    {
        // sends the email, removed code for Stackoverflow as not needed
    }

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api')->only('resend');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
}
```

If I'm right, the `6,1` means 6 requests per minutes? So not sure why it would respond with **Too Many Attempts** almost straight away.

Locally I use Mailtrap, in production I use Mailgun.

Comment: It means 6 requests allowed every 1 minute. If you want to make the limit greater just modify the numbers.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you